# basic $scope connection with model

Tags: angularjs

Its my code:

```
    .controller("GetAllAuthors", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/authors')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.authors = response.data;
        });
    $scope.edit = function (index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.authors[i].id == index) {
                $scope.object = $scope.authors[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Html view:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="author in authors">
<td><input type="button" ng-click="edit(author.id)" value="Edit"/></td>

<div ng-controller="GetAllAuthors">
    {{object.id}} // <--- doesn't display it
</div>
```

It's not working. I can't use date binding with my object. How fix it?

Comment: Share complete HTML. `ng-controller="GetAllAuthors"` looks misplaced

Answer (score 0):

You need to put http inside edit method.

```
 .controller("GetAllAuthors", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.edit = function (index) {

         $http.get('http://localhost:8080/authors')
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.authors = response.data;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.authors.length; i++) {
               if ($scope.authors[i].id == index) {
                   $scope.object = $scope.authors[i];
                   break;
               }
            }
        });


    }
})
```

Comment: Can u try console.log authors in your code. You can't access authors outside then because it is under boundary of promises. You can do it by added callback in http.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Initialize $scope.object outside the function.